# Problems running program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm learning C++ for the first time (im using microsoft visual studio code) and i'm trying to run my code based on the video im watching. I have exactly what he has in the video but i have an error;

PS C:\Users\Baseb> g++ cpplearning.cpp
g++ : The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
At line:1 char:1

- g++ cpplearning.cpp
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (g++:String) [], CommandNotFoundException   
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException .
  ```

I have downloaded minGW and the path i was using is; C:\MinGW\bin . Do you know why I am getting this error code? I typed G++ --version and it shows I do have G++ installed on my computer.

Thank You

Comment: Have you done all the configuration setup?  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Comment: You've installed VSCode, you've installed g++, what you haven't done (correctly) is make the connection between VSCode and g++.

Comment: "The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program" - You need to install the GCC / G++ compiler before you can use it.

Comment: You need to ensure that `g++` is on your PATH (the environment variable).

Comment: Could it be because the previous minGW version i had was a 32x not 64?

Comment: @Evo It says `is not recognized as the name` so it can't find it. Follow @Eljay link.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `g++` from a terminal and it is a Windows terminal (`cmd` or other), you have to include the `g++` binary path in the Windows `PATH` environment variable.

If you run the compiler from VS then follow the link from @Eljay comment.